# delete rows where two columns concatenation is duplicated

Tags: php, mysql

Table `teh` - `1400` rows.

I want to delete rows having `col1` and `col2` duplicated.

For example - if `col1` is `lorem` and `col2` is `ipsum`
and some next row also - `col1` is `lorem` and `col2` is `ipsum`
this `next` row should be deleted.

Here is the code I'm using and can't see what is wrong because the final result is - only one row is remaining, all others are deleted.

The table has at least half unique rows regarding `col1` and `col2` concatenation.

```
$st = $db->query("select id, col1, col2 from teh");
$st->execute();
$arr = $st->fetchAll();
$check = [];
foreach($arr as $el){
    $str = $el['col1'] . $el['col2'];
    if(in_array($str, $check)){
        $sql = "delete from teh where id = :aid";
        $st = $db->prepare($sql);
        $st->execute([":aid" => $el['id']]);
    }
    else{
        array_push($check, $str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$st = $db->query("select id, col1, col2 from teh");
$st->execute();
$arr = $st->fetchAll();
foreach($arr as $el){
    $sql = "delete from teh where col1 = acol1 and col2 = acol2 and id <> aid";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute([":acol1" => $el['col1'], ":acol2" => $el['col2'], ":aid" => $el['id']]);
}
```

The idea is to delete all the rows with the same values than the row you are checking at that moment but the `id` value is different. No need to concatenate and save it to an array this way.

Comment: you probably mean - `$sql = "delete from teh where col1 = :acol1 and col2 = :acol2 and id <> :aid";`

Comment: seems it works, about half of rows are remaining, have you any idea how to check that remaining rows are unique regarding `col1` and `col2` concatenation

Comment: All the remaining rows should have different values for `col1` and `col2` attributes so the concatenation should be unique as well

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete rows with higher `id` but the same `col1` and `col2` values, you can simply `DELETE` rows where a matching row exists with a lower `id` value

```
DELETE 
t1
FROM teh t1
JOIN teh t2 ON t2.col1 = t1.col1 AND t2.col2 = t1.col2 AND t2.id < t1.id
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=eac231dddd025f3144caea581f0cf8fb)

Comment: using your code - `628` rows are remaining. Using `jeprubio's` code - `610` rows are remaining. Could you find the reason, pls?

Comment: @qadenza that's a good question. Without seeing the data it's hard to be certain. Is it possible there are any `NULL` values?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are following a logic, I think you can do it without using a loop. If you want to delete duplicate records, you can do the following steps.

1. Get `id` of unique records (just use one-dimensional array return for this)

   `$sql = "SELECT id FROM teh GROUP BY col1, col2;";
   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();`
2. Use implode to convert array to string

   `$toString = implode(",",$result);`
3. delete records that are not in the list. (the result of the query above)

   `$sql = "DELETE FROM teh where id NOT IN ({$toString});";
   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();`

To complete it:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM teh GROUP BY col1, col2;";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$toString = implode(",",$result);

$sql = "DELETE FROM teh where id NOT IN ({$toString});";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note: Looping a SQL query might be a big problem in the long run. There's a lot of other ways to do this.